# Javascript - Regular expressions, what to do now that its all true

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I am working on a javascript that is supposed to test the password field. Now I was able to get the the password field to work out and display a alert if none of the requirements are not being met. However the next problem lies in what to do now that the requirements are true. I wrote a true statement to check to see if it it would click the button on the form to enter in the password but so far I can't seem to get it click the button. Any advice would be very welcomed and appreciated. Here is the code I have as of right now.

```
var str= passwordFieldForm; 
var patt=/[a-z]/g; 
var patt2 = /[A-Z]/g;  
var patt3 = /[0-9]/g;  
var patt4 = /[~\!@#\$%\^&*_\-\+=`\|\\(\)\{\}\[\]:;"'<>,\.\?\/]/g;  

var result=patt.test(str); 
var result2=patt2.test(str); 
var result3=patt3.test(str); 
var result4=patt4.test(str); 

if (!result) 
  alert("Needs a lowercase letter"); 

if (!result2) 
  alert("Needs a Uppercase Letter");

if (!result3) 
  alert("Needs a Number.") ;

if (!result4) 
  alert("Needs a special character"); 


if (result) && (result2) && (result3) && (result4) == true 
  document.getElementById("kioskform:broswerPasswordSubmit").click();
```

Comment: I think you mean ``if (result && result2 && result3 && result4) document.getElementById...``

Comment: Use what acheong87 showed. Yours is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Thank you very much guys , Works like a charm can't believe I forgot something so simple as that.

Comment: You should get rid of those `g` flags, too.  As it is, you're retrieving a list of all matches for each regex (or `null` if it doesn't match), when all you need is a simple yes/no test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`if`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5) statement expects an expression **between** parentheses, i.e.:

```
if (result && result2 && result3 && result4) {
  document.getElementById("kioskform:broswerPasswordSubmit").click(); 
}
```

Also, there's no need to explicitly compare the result against `true`. If the expression *evaluates* to `true`, its body will be executed, just like you used in the individual `if`s.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining me that, Can't believe I was missing that. Thank you.