# Javascript - Checking the password field with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, html, regex, forms

I am working on a regular expression to check the password field, Now the javascript that tests the varible is working, but when I try to call it and check the form I can't seem to get the javascript to see that I want it to check the password in the form with the javascript I made but I can't seem to get the form to commnuicate with the javascript I made, The form and the javascript are on the same page, what I want for it to do is after it checks the password requirements it will just go and submit the form. Here is what I have so far.

```
<html>
 <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function checkPassword(password)
    {
    password = document.getElementById('thethePasswordFieldField').value;   
        var patt=/[a-z]/g;
        var patt2 = /[A-Z]/g; 
        var patt3 = /[0-9]/g; 
        var patt4 = /[~\!@#\$%\^&*_\-\+=`\|\\(\)\{\}\[\]:;"'<>,\.\?\/]/g; 

            var result=patt.test(password);
            var result2=patt2.test(password);
            var result3=patt3.test(password);
            var result4=patt4.test(password);

                if (!result)
            alert("Needs a lowercase & uppercase letter, a number & a special character.");

                if (!result2)
            alert("Needs a lowercase & uppercase letter, a number & a special character.");

                if (!result3)
            alert("Needs a lowercase & uppercase letter, a number & a special character.");

                if (!result4)
            alert("Needs a lowercase & uppercase letter, a number & a special character.");

                        if (result && result2 && result3 && result4)
            alert("");
            document.getElementById('frmApplication').submit();
    }
    </script>

    <form id="frmApplication" name="frmApplication" action="test.html" method="post">
    Password: <input type="text" name="thethePasswordFieldField" id="thethePasswordFieldField">  
   <a href="javascript:checkPassword()">Submit</a>
   </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Isn't this the third time you're asking basically [the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644587/javascript-regular-expressions-what-to-do-now-that-its-all-true) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641842/regular-expression-testing-the-new-password)?

Comment: You are getting the input element by ID "password", but you have no element with `id="password"` in your HTML.

Comment: Why do you have `{` before the submit call?

Comment: Just a few suggestions: You don't need the `password` parameter declared for your function (since you aren't passing it). Set the `id` attribute for your `<input>` element to "password", so that `document.getElementById("password")` actually retrieves something. Remove the `{` before the `.submit()` line.

Comment: @ bfavaretto no just a continuation. I was asking for different things however it is centered around the same code.

Comment: @ Jonathan M sorry didn't see that. removing it now.

Comment: @GilbertV, please always post the actual code you're working with.

Comment: Just did, Posted as of right now. and ty for your help. I am still having some slight issues with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `getElementById` but have not actually assigned an ID attribute to the "password" field.

Try:

```
<input type="password" name="thePasswordField" id="thePasswordField"/>
```

The reason I suggest using this convention is to avoid using "password" as your actual field name (IE will probably die if you use this method) and to also of course, actually use a `password` type field.

Hopefully it should be obvious to you that your initial `getElementById` line must refer to the "thePasswordField" ID value.

I have not vetted the rest of your code, but put the ID attribute in there and give it a shot.

Comment: Thank you I replaced the line and tried it out still no results not sure what else I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

At the first sign your did not close all blocks

```
 function checkPassword(password)
    {
.....
   { document.getElementById('frmApplication').submit();
    }
```

see here about regexp [how-to-validate-password-with-regular-expression](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-password-with-regular-expression/)

Comment: Thank you, just closed the blocks and renamed the password id but still no results . though the how to validate-password page doesn't really help much being that java and JS aren't that similar.